# Cordova App. Xcode: The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova app for iOS.

I downloaded the repo into another pc (can't go back to old one) and tried to run simulator. Until now it worked, but now It's giving some issue:

```
The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content.
```

Any ideas??
[image]

Comment: in general settings, launch image option try either selecting 'dont use asset catalog' option or 'launchimage'. try by altering them once. it is because launch image icons in that app are not compatible to xcode you are using. So if not getting, delete launch icon from there and clean and build

Comment: @Sascuash how did you solve it?  i did what Avis wrote but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use exact image sizes for these kind of issues.

```
Default: 320 × 480
Default@2x: 640 × 960
Default-568h@2x: 640 × 1136
Default-667h@2x: 750 × 1334
Default-736h@3x: 1080 × 1920
```

Use these sizes to solve this problem

Comment: how to generate these images?